# JS success как иконка

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как заместо слова "Обновлено" добавить иконку например `<i class='icon fa fa-check'></i>` которая плавно исчезнет через пару секунд?
Вот такой код у меня:

```
success: function(json) {
alert("Обновлено");
}
```

Спасибо)

Comment: Ни как. В `alert()` иконку ты не засунешь...

Comment: Создай кастомное модальное окно или используй уже готовые плагины.

Comment: Советую для этих целей использовать SweetAlert . https://sweetalert.js.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо alert используй fadeOut блока с иконкой

```js
$("#block").show();
$("#block").fadeOut(2000);
```

```css
#block{
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    }
    
#block i{     position: relative;
    font-size: 45px;
    padding: 28px 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div id="block"><i class='icon fa fa-check'></i></div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!! Это то о чём я и говорил) Прям очень круто!)